# Can you set what color VS2008 uses to highlight a finally block?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I switched over to a [dark visual studio theme](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/06/Join-the-Dark-Side-of-Visual-Studio.aspx) a couple months ago. I think it helps a lot with strain and I've noticed I get less headaches. However, when I'm debugging and I hit a finally block it highlights the try and finally block with a white background which drowns out all my code. Anyone know how to change what color VS uses to highlight a finally block?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it, it's the "Read-Only Region" display item.

Comment: Thank you! This is a lifesaver, I had exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah - you should be able to control all of the fine-grain color stuff.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165337.aspx

I'm not sure which specific item you want, but the link should get you to the right properties page.

- Select Options from the Tools menu,
  and in the Environment folder, select
  Fonts and Colors.
- The Fonts and Colors, Environment, Options Dialog Box
  opens.
- In Show settings for, select Text Editor.

Comment: I should have been more specific. I played around with the fonts and colors options for the text editor, but I couldn't find a display item that changed the highlight color of a finally block. That display item (if it exists) is what I am looking for.

Comment: My bad!  I misunderstood :)  Glad you found it